# Plural of -choron and -hedroid suffixes?

Tags: grammatical-number, suffixes

Many 4D shapes carry the suffixes *-choron* and *-hedroid* (such as that as the *hexadecachoron/hexadecahedroid*).

What would the general plural forms of these suffixes be? Only reason I ask is hope that one of them differs from the regular *'add an s on the end'* pluralization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decahedron) accepts either *decahedrons* or *decahedra*.  As does [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/decahedron).  (Oxford Online apparently thinks there can never be more than one.)  Alas, can't get the dictionaries to recognize any "-hedroid" variants.

However, "octachoron" is recognized by both Wictionary and YourDictionary, and both accept either "octachorons" or "octachora".